# How to show keyboard after used inputView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, uipickerview, inputview

I used `inputView` to show `uipickerview` for my `textfield`, but I use same `textfield` for other functions. How can I show standard keyboard after I used `inputView` for that `textfield`?

```
textfield.inputView = pickrView;
```

Comment: textfield.inputView = NO; worked for me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just

`textfield.inputView = nil;`

worked for me

Comment: you'd better use nil or NULL instead of NO. The inputView property expects an UIView and not a BOOL. Although this works with NO as nil and NO are both a numerical 0, this will fail and crash if you assign YES.

Answer (score 5):

As Pavel Kaljunen said, you need only to set the inputView to nil, but when the keyboard is already visible, you have to resignFirstResponder first, set the inputView to nil and then becomeFirstResponder again.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35];

[yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
yourTextField.inputView = nil;
[yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this code maybe can work

```
 [textField.inputView addTarget:self action:@selector(doTest) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)doTest
{
  if([textFiled isFirstResponder])
  {
    [textFiled resignFirstResponder];
  }
  else
  {
    [textFiled becomeFirstResponder];
  }
}
```